# prevent an element from going beyond the bounds of another element

Tags: javascript

I want to add an eye function to my application, the pupils must follow the movement of the mouse arrow and at the same time not go beyond the eyes

```
<style>

.eyes {
  width:800px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
}
.data {
  border-left:190px solid #bbb;
  border-right:130px solid #bbb;
  border-top:100px solid;
  border-bottom:100px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}
#round-left {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:57px;
  z-index:2;
  border:29px solid green;
}
#round-right {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  left:560px;
  top:57px;
  z-index:2;
  border:29px solid green;
}
.left {
  float:left;
  border-radius:0 100%;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
}
.right {
  float:right;
  border-radius:100% 0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);

}

</style>
            <div class="eyes">
                <div class="data right">  </div>
                <canvas  id="round-right">  </canvas>
                 <div class="data left"></div>
                 <canvas  id="round-left">  </canvas>
            </div>
```

I attach the pupil to the movement of the mouse arrow.
I do not understand how I can find the boundaries of the eyes to prevent the pupils from leaving them.

```
<script>
    let eyeLeft = document.querySelector('#round-left');
    let eyeRight = document.querySelector('#round-right');
    let dataLeft = document.querySelectorAll('.data left');
    let dataRight = document.querySelector('.data right');

document.onmousemove  = (e) => {
            eyeLeft.style.transform = `translate(${e.clientX - 450}px, ${e.clientY -450}px)`;
         }

    </script>
```

Comment: post it as a snippet

Comment: Use [Math.hypot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) to calculate the distance between the centre points. If the distance is is greater than the difference of the radii of the eye and the pupil, then you're going out of the border.

Comment: You have a couple of canvas elements in there and I suspect they are there so that you can draw the eyes on them and note whether the color of the gray is totally under the eyeball or not. Is this your understanding? Otherwise you have a difficult geometry problem as the gray areas have odd boundaries.